# How to access a list, that is passed to a proc to be modified, outside of that proc in TCL?

Tags: list, tcl, proc

In my TCL script I am passing an empty list as argument to a proc.
Inside the proc, I am adding values to the list.
But outside of that proc, the values of list is not reflected.
How can I access the same list which is modified within the proc ?

Note : I do not want to return from the proc due to some reasons which I have not mentioned here in the interest of keeping my requirement simple.

```
proc addNames { names } {
    lappend names tom
    lappend names harry
    puts $names
}

set names {}
addNames $names 

puts "Outside of proc: names"
puts $names
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `return` in your proc, then you [could use `upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/upvar.html) e.g.

```
proc addNames { names } {
    upvar 1 names n
    lappend n tom
    lappend n harry
}

set names {}
addNames $names
```

However, note that this creates a dependency in your proc on the existence of `names` in the calling environment. A more flexible approach might be to pass in a parameter with the name of the `names` variable:

```
proc addNames {varName} {
    upvar 1 $varName n
    lappend n tom
    lappend n harry
}

set names {}
addNames names
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For your second suggestion, there is no need for the first parameter (notice that it is not used in the proc body).

Comment: @SchelteBron oh yes, good spot!